# SQL Join on multiple columns where not in table 2

Tags: sql-server

Setup:
Table 1 - Lists All Groups

Table 1 columns - GroupID, GroupDescription

Table 2 - Lists All Sites and associated groups by permission tier.

Table 2 columns - SiteID, SiteName, GroupT1, GroupT2, GroupT3, GroupT4, GroupT5

To describe this, each site as 5 tiers of groups, where each group corresponds to certain levels of permission at that site.

I'm trying to identify tbl1.GroupID that are not used in any of the tbl2 group tier columns, in order to remove these unused permission groups.

I've tried left join of tbl1 with tbl2 but I can't find the combination of "on" and "where" to get what I need. I usually end up with entries from tbl1 that are "null" on some of the rows in tbl2, but they still appear in other placed on tbl2.

What I need is the tbl1 rows that do not appear at all in tbl2.
In the example data below, All "approver C" groups are not used for any sites, and that's what I want to isolate.

Thanks

Table 1 Example Data:

```
Group ID    Group Description
T1a         Tier 1 Approver A
T2a         Tier 2 Approver A
T3a         Tier 3 Approver A
T4a         Tier 4 Approver A
T5a         Tier 5 Approver A
T1b         Tier 1 Approver B
T2b         Tier 2 Approver B
T3b         Tier 3 Approver B
T4b         Tier 4 Approver B
T5b         Tier 5 Approver B
T1c         Tier 1 Approver C
T2c         Tier 2 Approver C
T3c         Tier 3 Approver C
T4c         Tier 4 Approver C
T5c         Tier 5 Approver C
```

Table 2 Example Data

```
SiteID  SiteDesc    ApprT1  ApprT2  ApprT3  ApprT4  ApprT5
1       Site1       T1A     T2B     T3B     T4B     T5A
2       Site2       T1A     T2A     T3B     T4A     T5A
3       Site3       T1B     T2B     T3B     T4B     T5A
4       Site4       T1B     T2A     T3B     T4A     T5A
```

Attempted query

```
select distinct gr.GroupID from
Group_Info$ gi
join Site_Info$ si on
si.ApprT1 is null and
si.ApprT2 is null and
si.ApprT3 is null and
si.ApprT4 is null and
si.ApprT5 is null
```

Comment: Post your Query And Sample Data

Comment: Updated main page with data and query. What I need is the tbl1 rows that do not appear at all in tbl2. In the example data, all "approver C" groups are not used for any sites, and that's what I want to isolate.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
--Try This
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1 (GroupId NVARCHAR(5),[Group Description] NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #TABLE2 (SiteID INT,SiteDesc NVARCHAR(50), ApprT1 NVARCHAR(50), ApprT2 NVARCHAR(50),ApprT3 NVARCHAR(50),ApprT4  NVARCHAR(50), ApprT5  NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #TABLE1
SELECT 'T1a','Tier 1 Approver A'  UNION ALL
SELECT'T2a', 'Tier 2 Approver A'UNION ALL
SELECT'T3a','Tier 3 Approver A'UNION ALL
SELECT'T4a','Tier 4 Approver A'UNION ALL
SELECT'T5a','Tier 5 Approver A'UNION ALL
SELECT'T1b','Tier 1 Approver B'UNION ALL
SELECT'T2b','Tier 2 Approver B'UNION ALL
SELECT'T3b','Tier 3 Approver B'UNION ALL
SELECT'T4b','Tier 4 Approver B'UNION ALL
SELECT'T5b','Tier 5 Approver B'UNION ALL
SELECT'T1c','Tier 1 Approver C'UNION ALL
SELECT'T2c','Tier 2 Approver C'UNION ALL
SELECT'T3c','Tier 3 Approver C'UNION ALL
SELECT'T4c','Tier 4 Approver C'UNION ALL
SELECT'T5c','Tier 5 Approver C'


INSERT INTO #TABLE2
SELECT 1,'Site1','T1A','T2B','T3B','T4B','T5A'UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Site2','T1A','T2A','T3B','T4A','T5A'UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Site3','T1B','T2B','T3B','T4B','T5A'UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Site4','T1B','T2A','T3B','T4A','T5A'



SELECT * FROM #TABLE1
SELECT * FROM #TABLE2
SELECT * FROM #TABLE1 WHERE GroupId NOT IN (SELECT ApprT1 FROM #TABLE2 )AND GroupId NOT IN (SELECT ApprT2 FROM #TABLE2 )
AND GroupId NOT IN (SELECT ApprT3 FROM #TABLE2 )AND GroupId NOT IN (SELECT ApprT4 FROM #TABLE2 )AND GroupId NOT IN (SELECT ApprT5 FROM #TABLE2 )

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`cross apply(values ...)`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to unpivot the five `ApprT[1-5]` columns in `Site_Info$` and `not exists()` to find which `GroupId`s from `Group_Info$` do not exist in that list.

```
select *
from Group_Info$ gi
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Site_Info$ si
    cross apply (values (ApprT1),(ApprT2),(ApprT3),(ApprT4),(ApprT5)
      ) u (GroupId)
  where gi.GroupId = u.GroupId
);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OFI50245

returns:

```
+---------+-------------------+
| GroupId | GroupDescription  |
+---------+-------------------+
| T3a     | Tier 3 Approver A |
| T5b     | Tier 5 Approver B |
| T1c     | Tier 1 Approver C |
| T2c     | Tier 2 Approver C |
| T3c     | Tier 3 Approver C |
| T4c     | Tier 4 Approver C |
| T5c     | Tier 5 Approver C |
+---------+-------------------+
```

---

It might make it easier to read using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), or it might not:

```
;with cte as (
  select u.GroupId
  from Site_Info$ si
    cross apply (values (ApprT1),(ApprT2),(ApprT3),(ApprT4),(ApprT5)
      ) u (GroupId)
)
select *
from Group_Info$ gi
where not exists (
  select 1
  from cte
  where gi.GroupId = cte.GroupId
  )
```

---

One way to isolate 'Approver C' is by the last letter in `GroupDescription`, and we can use aggregation along with the previous method of unpivoting the data to find those Approvers who do not appear in `Site_Info$`:

```
select 
    Approver = right(GroupDescription,1)
  , ApproverGroupCount = count(gi.GroupId)
  , ApproverSiteCount = count(si.GroupId)
from Group_Info$ gi
  left join (
    select distinct u.GroupId
    from Site_Info$ si
      cross apply (values (ApprT1),(ApprT2),(ApprT3),(ApprT4),(ApprT5)
        ) u (GroupId)
      ) si
    on gi.GroupId = si.GroupId
group by right(GroupDescription,1)
having count(si.GroupId) = 0;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/USVYSO98254

returns:

```
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Approver | ApproverGroupCount | ApproverSiteCount |
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
| C        |                  5 |                 0 |
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

We can wrap up that query in a common table expression and use it to join to `Group_Info$` to return all of the rows for Approver C:

```
with cte as (
  select 
      Approver = right(GroupDescription,1)
  from Group_Info$ gi
    left join (
      select distinct u.GroupId
      from Site_Info$ si
        cross apply (values (ApprT1),(ApprT2),(ApprT3),(ApprT4),(ApprT5)
          ) u (GroupId)
        ) si
      on gi.GroupId = si.GroupId
  group by right(GroupDescription,1)
  having count(si.GroupId) = 0
)
select gi.*
from group_info$ gi
  inner join cte 
    on right(gi.GroupDescription,1) = cte.Approver
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/USVYSO98254

returns:

```
+---------+-------------------+
| GroupId | GroupDescription  |
+---------+-------------------+
| T1c     | Tier 1 Approver C |
| T2c     | Tier 2 Approver C |
| T3c     | Tier 3 Approver C |
| T4c     | Tier 4 Approver C |
| T5c     | Tier 5 Approver C |
+---------+-------------------+
```

---

Reference:

- [**`apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [table value constructor `(values (...),(...))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)
- [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)